# what is the need of multiple class modifiers in java?

Tags: java

While reading oracles Java documentation(chapter 8) I came across this interesting piece of line:

"**If two or more (distinct) class modifiers** appear in a class declaration, then it is customary, though not required, that they appear in the order consistent with that shown above in the production for ClassModifier."

and here is the  Class Modifiers

```
ClassModifiers:

    ClassModifier
    ClassModifiers ClassModifier

ClassModifier: one of

    Annotation public protected private
    abstract static final strictfp
```

My question is what is the need for multiple class modifiers? when we can make use of multiple class modifiers?

Answer (score 7):

Well, you can have a `public abstract static strictfp` inner class; each one of those is orthogonal to the rest. In general, you can group them in the following way:

- `public`/`protected`/`private`: access modifiers - determining who has access to the class literal.
- `abstract`/`final`: inheritance modifiers
- `static`: only for inner classes
- `strictfp`: it's orthogonal to everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Two examples:

```
public final class MyClass { }
protected abstract class MyClass {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, to create a class that has the features dictated by several modifiers. Not all the modifiers are mutually exclusive. For example, `abstract` disallows making instances of the class, and `public` makes the class accessible even outside its package. Hence, to make an abstract class that's accessible outside its own package, you'd need to make it `public abstract class`.